# Change Limit before Mac Notifies You That The "Startup Disk Is Full"?

Tags: notifications

I always have this problem: Immediately after Mac Notifies You That The "Startup Disk Is Full", it pauses many of the applications I am using (eg. 6 out of 10), and this always makes me lose my unsaved data. How does this mechanism work? Can I change a parameter so that Mac notifies me *earlier* (e.g. instead of 1GB short of full, mayb 8GB) and/or doesn't pause my applications?

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/138088/how-do-i-change-when-os-x-warns-about-low-disk-space) there isn't a way to configure this. Someone [wrote a shell script here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=110136) to check the disk space and show you an alert message if it's getting full.

If you're familiar with the command line, you can save it somewhere and create a cron job to run it every few hours or so. I tested it and it worked fine.